# jQuery ajax callback load content displayed twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

When doing the following ajax call, the "load" function reloads the updated content, but the content prior to ajax call is also still visible. So, you see the "pre-ajax content" & the "post-ajax content" in one page:

```
    <script>

            function myUnPause(elm) {
                  var table = $('#realtime').dataTable(); 
                  var extension = $(elm).closest("tr").find('td.extension').text();
          var agent = $(elm).closest("tr").find('td.name').text();
          alert(extension.trim()+ ' will be unpaused and put back in the Queue');

    $.ajax("/cura/pages/realtime/realtime2.php",{
        type: "GET",
        data:   
        {
        action:'agentpause',
        pauselocation: (extension.trim()),
        queue: 'testq',
        paused: 'false'
        },
        success: function(msg){
            $("#myunpause").load('/cura/includes/realtime.inc.php');
        }           
    });

    }       
</script>
```

The php script displaying this content is referred to from the /cura/pages/realtime/realtime2.php page as:

```
<?php include '../../includes/realtime.inc.php'; ?>
```

Is this causing the old content to stay on the same page?

Any ideas how to change it so only the update content is displayed?

Comment: are you sure the ajax response is not sending the pre-ajax content as part of its response

Comment: Shouldn't, the ajax call updates something on DB, and then doesnt send anything back when successful. From response headers I can see: `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`

Comment: from Google Chrome i can see when clicking the button, there are 2 calls: `realtime2.php?action=agentpause&pauselocation=Agent%2F1702&queue=testq&paused=true 
realtime.inc.php`

Comment: Noone any suggestions/ideas? Been playing around with remove(), but to no avail so far.